# Insert node of linked list at the end but program keep crashing

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

As the title say, I tried to insert node of linked list ***at the end*** but **C++** program keep crashing

```
class SymbolTable
{
  struct Node
  {
    string id;
    int num;
    string str;
    Node *next;
  };

public:
  SymbolTable() {}
  void insert(string id);

private:
  Node head = { "head", -99, "", nullptr};
};



void SymbolTable::insert(string id)
{
  Node *traverser = &(this->head);
  while (traverser != nullptr) { traverser = traverser->next; }

  Node *newNode = new Node();
  newNode->id = id;
  newNode->next = nullptr;
  traverser->next = newNode; // --> Crashing
}
```

I don't see any problem.

***Answer***:

traverser != nullptr should be traverser->next != nullptr

Comment: Think for a while what `traverser` is when the loop ends. What condition must be met for the loop to end?

Comment: Ugrh... I was doing right ._. Why I change that line ._.

Comment: Aesthetic note: your `while` loop could easily be a `for` loop. E.g. `for (traverser = &(this->head); traverser != nullptr; traverser = traverser->next);`

Comment: @Chris Wow! OwO

Comment: Why do you have a head node instead of a pointer to the first node?  There is no need for a head node.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Do you mean pointer to head node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do find few problems, first of all in-class definition you declared function insert as:

```
void insert(string id, string type);
```

however, when you declare a function outside of it you skipped 2nd argument:

```
void SymbolTable::insert(string id);
```

I don't understand how this code would even compile.
I also fixed algorithm itself:

```
void SymbolTable::insert(string id)
{
    Node* traverser = &(this->head);
    while (traverser->next != nullptr) //used to be (traverse !=nullptr)
    { 
      traverser = traverser->next;
    }

    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->id = id;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    traverser->next = newNode; 
}
```

Issue was that you were checking if traverse is null, not if the next of traverser is null. In consequence, you were referring to traverser which was a nullpointer. After this little fix code compiles just fine after inserting.

Comment: I forget to remove when edit code to post. But thanks anyway